# Callback never called when publishing to gcloud pubsub

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have an application that sends messages to Google Cloud Pubsub. Until before yesterday it was working fine, but then it started hanging when calling (Coffeescript code below):

```
topic.publish data, (err, data) ->
      console.error err if err
      callback(err)
```

It happens a few times per minute, not always, but when it happens the callback is never called, also the message never arrives, meaning that I'll lose this data. I've never had problems like this before and I've been using pubsub for 3 months.

I've already tried updating the package, deploying to another machine and creating a new topic, but always with the same results. Is it happening to anyone else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be fixed on `google-cloud` package version `0.46.2`. You can view [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/1955) for more information.